# Enabling hibernation of Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 with swap on /dev/sda3

Tags: partitioning, swap, hibernate, budgie

I've been trying to enable hibernation on my new Budgie installation. `swapon` indicates that my swap partition is located in `/dev/sda3`, and I have come to the point where I need to edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`, passing `resume` and `resume_offset` parameters. I'm, having problems with getting that offset, when I run `sudo filefrag -v /dev/sda3 |grep " 0:"| awk '{gsub(/\.\./,""); print $4}'` it returns anything in the console, and when I run `sudo filefrag -v /dev/sda3` I get `Filesystem type is: 1021994`, but using this as `resume_offset` returns `Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation` even when I have a 18Gi swap partition with 16Gi of RAM, so I think the problem should be related to that cutoff value I'm getting.

So, how could I access to the cutoff of `/dev/sda3`? and, in the `resume` variable, the `UUID` corresponds of the UUID of my swap or my root partition? I have seen tutorials using the direction of the swap partition in some sites and `/` in others. I've tried to understand the commands so I can edit them for my situation but I don't know if I'm missing something, I'll be very grateful with your help.